# joining query returning wrong output

Tags: mysql

I have 4 tables in my database

First table: student

```
id  Name   roll   wheree    final
1   vivek  22222  leave     65000
2   abc    33333  admission 50000
```

Second table: fee

```
id  amount   roll   refund 
1   9250     22222  no
2   5000     22222  no
2   5000     33333  no
2   7000     22222  yes
```

Third table: pdc

```
id  amount   roll   refund   statuss
1   9250     22222  no       recived
2   9250     22222  no       cleared
2   6000     22222  yes      recived
```

Fourth table: discount

```
id    amount       roll     
1     5000         22222    
2     6500         22222    
2     6000         33333
```

I am trying to run

```
select student.id,student.roll,student.name as
stu,student.final,ifnull(sum(gst_amount),0) as other,
(student.final-ifnull(sum(gst_amount),0)) as fee_to_paid,
ifnull(sum(fee.amount),0) as fee_deposit,(student.final-ifnull(sum(gst_amount),0)
-ifnull(sum(fee.amount),0)
-ifnull(sum(pdc.amount),0)) as fee_remain,ifnull(sum(pdc.amount),0) as pdc,count(fee.amount) 
as tot_ins from student left join fee on fee.roll=student.roll
 left join discount on discount.roll=student.roll left join pdc
 on pdc.roll=student.roll where
  wheree!='inquiry' where roll='22222'  GROUP by student.roll
```

I want this output.

```
id roll   final  other  fee_to_paid fee_deposit pdc    fee_remain   tot_ins
1  22222  65000  11000  54000       7250        9250   37500        2
```

I want to less the amount from fee which refund value is y and same from pdc

Comment: In which table gst_amount amount belong?

Comment: in discount table instead of amount

Comment: how pdc can be 9250 ? can u please explain the formula for pdc to be 9250

Comment: we have one 3 pdc of 22222 roll and one is cleared which amount is 9250 has been added in fee and other pdc has been returned to student so we only have one pdc and pdc means post dated cheque

Comment: Except for your first table your tables seem to have no PRIMARY KEY. This will prove problematic.

Answer (score 0):

I have read your question and observe your tables data and your query.You have not specified the Where clause for  **fee and pdc table** for **refunds value yes.**
So, try this below query i have correct that...

```
select  student.id
    ,student.roll
    ,student.name as stu
    ,student.final
    ,ifnull(sum(gst_amount),0) as other
    ,(student.final-ifnull(sum(gst_amount),0)) as fee_to_paid
    ,ifnull(sum(fee.amount),0) as fee_deposit,(student.final-ifnull(sum(gst_amount),0)-ifnull(sum(fee.amount),0)-ifnull(sum(pdc.amount),0)) as fee_remain
    ,ifnull(sum(pdc.amount),0) as pdc,count(fee.amount) as tot_ins 
    from student left join fee on fee.roll=student.roll AND fee.refund='yes'
                     left join discount on discount.roll=student.roll 
                 left join pdc on pdc.roll=student.roll AND pdc.refund='yes' AND  wheree!='inquiry' 
where student.roll='22222'  GROUP by student.roll
```

Comment: it's giving me error how can we put where condition after between join

Comment: i have edited my answer its my mistack for that where clause instead of that try AND .. check my last edited answer

Comment: but its not giving my expected answer

Comment: You want to sure about each and every table that Where LEFT join required or inner join requires...

Comment: so now the problem is in your join

Comment: so what should i do

Comment: first of all find the difference between inner join and left join then return to your query that where inner join requires instead of left join

Comment: and try one by one table join in this query not at a time join all tables

Comment: first try two tables join and observes the data if the data is correct than try third tables join again  verify the data is correct or some duplicate records given ,if data is correct than join another table and again observe the correct data

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182909/discussion-between-vivek-modi-and-dipak-rathod).